# vkCreateInstance() failing for known validation layers

Tags: android, vulkan

I'm getting into Vulkan development on Android and am finding that some of the validation layers reported by `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties()` cause `vkCreateInstance()` to return `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT`.

I'm working from Google's validation layer [example](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/validation-layer.html), as well as the validation chapter from [Vulkan-Tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers). Through trial and error, I've found that I'm able to create a `VkInstance` when requesting *some* of the SDK's provided layers but not others.

After following the setup steps in Google's guide above, my APK contains seven `libVkLayer_foo.so` files for each architecture and `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties()` lists seven layers, as expected. But when I try to create a `VkInstance` with any of the layers below, `vkCreateInstance()` returns `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT`:

- VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation
- VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker
- VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects

Does anyone know what might cause this? I assumed that if `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties()` knows about a layer, `vkCreateInstance()` should too. Although, I do see a [crash](https://gist.github.com/HeyLookItsBrandon/eaf9f22f2acec46314e21d60570cebf7) occurring in `libvulkan.so` immediately after `vkCreateInstance()` returns. I'm not sure if that is the cause of the `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT` or a result.

If it makes any difference, this is running on an nVidia Shield TV.

**Update** Oddly enough, the layers that cause a crash seem to be changing. Now I'm able to use `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation`, even though requesting that layer used to cause a crash.

And just to clarify, I only experience crashes when I use certain validation layers provided in the LunarG SDK on Android. I am able to create a `VkInstance` with the other validation layers and my callback function **does** get called.

Comment: try just creating and destroying an instance without any layers at all. Make sure that doesn't crash.  If it does, there's probably something else wrong with your VkInstanceCreateInfo struct

Comment: Based on the `bt` and function names it sounds like it does some window initialization when it crashes. I mean that makes sense. If `vkCreateInstance` failed, then any subsequent instance-level Vulkan command fails (you do not have any valid `VkInstance`).

Comment: @Jherico Without the validation layers, the app initializes fine. And like I mention in the post, the app continues to work when I use _certain_ layers. For example, `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` does *not* cause the app to crash but the ones I listed *do*. If it works for some layers, I assume that my `VkInstanceCreateInfo` is fine but if you have any troubleshooting suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @krOoze I could see that – that the crash is a result of the failure and probably not the cause. Although that brings me back to why creating an instance fails when I request some layers but not others. :)

Comment: Try to make a log by running with `VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all`. Should contain something relevant...

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being a more general C/C++ "undefined behavior" issue, which is probably why the "trouble" layer changed at one point. Consider a block of code like this, where `extensions` is a `std::vector`:

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
...
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t) extensions.size();
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
```

In general, this works fine. **But** the code to create the `VkInstanceCreateInfo` is in a helper method and `extensions` goes out of scope (i.e., is destroyed) before `createInfo` is used. So `vkCreateInstance` ends up with a pointer to memory that's been deallocated.